# Source files No such directory?

Tags: c, dev-c++

I have a project which includes two source files and one header file (wich contains the prototype of a function defined in one of the source files named `Get.c`), the problem is:

when I include the `Get.c` in the other source file, it gives me the error

`error : Get.c: No such file or directory ?`, even when I have all the three files in one directory. ---I use dev-cpp - .

Comment: To start with, *don't* include source files, only header files.

Comment: You include a .c file?

Comment: prototype is in header then why are you including .c??

Comment: how are you including Get.c?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Never say never :-)

Comment: you can #include C files in certain circumstances and under those circumstances, you should. ie. the way ffmpeg, libx264 and other libraries such as those implement the MMX, SSE and raw C versions of their methods

Comment: @meaning-matters Like everything else, there are of course exceptions to that. :) But in 99.99% of cases my original statement holds. :)

Comment: May I suggest you read a book on beginning C development as this will be time well spent in the short to long term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C you should be including the interface file (.h file), not the C source file (.c file). Create an interface for your module and include it respectively.

Comment: you can #include C files in certain circumstances and under those circumstances, you should. ie. the way ffmpeg, libx264 and other libraries such as those implement the MMX, SSE and raw C versions of their methods

Comment: Weird that this was upvoted and accepted when it doesn't even remotely answer the question, and just repeats what was mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @bizzehdee, yea you are absolutely right but I don't think the OP is intending to do this with a specific, beneficial purpose behind it.